# How can I convert AngularJS application into Node.JS application struture to work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am learning `Node.js` and `AngularJS` now a days ! I have done sample angularjs appliation like below(If I enter: `npm install` on `cmd` prompt, it's working fine, but it's totally `front-end` application now), but I want to convert this same application into `Node.js/Expres.js` with `back-end`. So that I can work with `database` like `Mongo` or any, and with any other `server-side` development work. Please let me know how can I integrate this structure to work as both(`AngularJS` as a front-end and `Node.js` as a `back-end`). Please provide me any solutions or any structures for it to work as front-end and back-end and thank you in advance for help !

Comment: There is perfect structure. Check MEAN JS to start

Comment: http://meanjs.org/docs/0.3.x/

Comment: @Weedoze, yes I have checked it and working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Sikorski, yes I have checked the same and working fine now. Thanks.